# OPENID with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, authentication, openid, flash-builder

Is it possible to implement OPENID in flex? I have search in GOOGLE regarding this. This is the best example i got so far [flex openid component](http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2009.02.17.html). But it is not working properly. it never redirect client to the login page. Can you please let me know how to do it. 
Im a new developer to flex and openID. I really need to implement this in flex. It related to my Final Year project.

It will be really helpful. Thank you

(i'm using flash builder)

Comment: You need to do the redirect part by yourself for the flex openid component.  Then, what is your problem?

Comment: my problem is how to do it. I don't have a clue of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for a way to add OpenId in flex, this is how I did it.(It might not be the best way to do it, but couldn't find any help in the internet on how to do this.)

We need to have the login page in a web page for openId. First create your login page with openid support.
Then in the flex side call this login page using

After validating the login, redirects to flex using a javascript function calling the flex side.

These links helped me when doing this
http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/
http://www.rogue-development.com/blog/category/air/